# Delete from list in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm beginner in SWI-Prolog and I have a problem. Please help me. 
How can I delete the last occurence of 9 from a list?

Examples:

```
?- delete([9,9,9])
[9,9]
?- delete([9,4,1,2,3,9,53,2,9,2])
[9,4,1,2,3,9,53,2,2]
```

Comment: First, you need a second argument!

Answer (score 0):

You have to 1) decompose the list into a `Prefix` list (which may contains 9s), a `[9]` one-element list and a `Suffix` list (which contains no 9s), then concatenate the `Prefix` and `Suffix` lists. Write a predicate which discovers the `Prefix` and the `Suffix` given a list `L`.

If we don't think procedurally or along the line of "how much is that gonna cost in CPU", the predicate `decompose(List,Prefix,Suffix)` which discovers `Prefix` and `Suffix` can be written in one single clause, a pure logical statement, using `append/2` and `member/2` and negation as failure.

One just needs a second line to cover the case where there are no 9s in the `List` to start with.